# ASP.NET Excel formatting and export

Tags: asp.net, excel, format

I've attached a pic below for better understanding of what format I want for my excel. I got no idea how to start to format excel using ASP.NET at all. Please do guide me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bring above format in Datatable of dataset & then just pass that datatable to following function.

```
string path = Context.Server.MapPath("~/ExcelData/test.xslx");
 ExportDataSet(ds, path);
```

private void ExportDataSet(DataSet ds, string destination)
{
    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

```
    workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

    workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

    foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
    {

        var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
        sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
        string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

        uint sheetId = 1;
        if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
        {
            sheetId =
                sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
        }

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

        List<String> columns = new List<string>();
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
            headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
        }


        sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
        {
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
            foreach (String col in columns)
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                newRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
        }

    }
}
```

}

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
```

Comment: Sorry as pasted code is not in good format, so you can see this on this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826614/how-to-write-data-on-new-sheet-of-excel

Comment: If let say I want this to be on a button. What are the exact code should I write? Mind providing me with the complete code? Thank you so much!

Comment: On button click you need to bring data in Dataset by Stored procedure,so that you can pass that to function written above. It will do all things & create excel file at specified path. Download openXML Sdk (2.0) & add references to project & on page.