# Generating Excel Sheet using HtmlWriter

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-5.0

i am generating Excel report using string writer.i generated the excel sheet but it generats only one sheet.but i need to create sheets based on my condition.
    my code is:

```
   string filename = "DownloadMobileNoExcel.xls";
   System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    tw.Write("<table>");
    tw.Write("<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td><td>data4</td><td>data5</td><td>data6</td></tr>");
    tw.Write("<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td><td>data4</td><td>data5</td><td>data6</td></tr>");
    tw.Write("<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td><td>data3</td><td>data4</td><td>data5</td><td>data6</td></tr>");
    tw.Write("</table>");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
    this.EnableViewState = false;
    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

The above Code generate single sheet but i want to create based on my condtion,how can i create sheets,i want same method which would to append the Html ,advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it can be done using frames: you'll have to create one .html file for each tab you want in the Excel sheet.

To see how it works, 
- create an Excel file with 2 sheets
- Save As... .html
- look at the html written (+ the subfolder generated containing the sheets

If you create a similar structure (using the files from the above test as templates), Excel will be able to open it.

Another approach is to create an Excel file using OpenXml, as decribed here:
[How to write data on new sheet of EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826614/how-to-write-data-on-new-sheet-of-excel)